# Delete the log file after archiving using NLog C#

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog, archive

I want to archive log files periodically(for every hour) from "Logs" folder to "Archive" folder and then delete those archived files from "logs" folder immediately. Can we achieve this using NLog?

Currently, I am using the below c# code for archiving, but I am not seeing the desired output. We are using Nlog version 4.7.11.

```
target.FileName = @"C:\Logs\Log-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd-hh}.log";
target.ArchiveFileName = @"C:\Archives\Log-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd-hh}.log";
target.ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Hour;
target.ArchiveOldFileOnStartup = true;
target.DeleteOldFileOnStartup = true;
target.MaxArchiveDays = 10;
target.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date;
target.MaxArchiveFiles = 50;
target.ArchiveDateFormat = "yyyy-mmm-dd hh-mm";
target.EnableArchiveFileCompression = true;
```

Comment: Please update your question to also include `target.FileName`-option

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog supports 2 file-archive-modes:

- Static FileName Archive-mode, where `ArchiveEvery` controls when to roll.
- Dynamic FileName Archive-mode, where `FileName` contains `${date}` or `${shortdate}` (Rolls automatically)

NLog does not support mixing these 2 file-archive-modes. If you want files to be moved into the Archive-folder, then you must use static FileName:

```cs
target.FileName = @"C:\Logs\App.log";
target.ArchiveFileName = @"C:\Archives\App-{#}.log.zip";
target.ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Hour;
target.ArchiveOldFileOnStartup = true;
target.DeleteOldFileOnStartup = true;
target.MaxArchiveDays = 10;
target.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.DateAndSequence;
target.MaxArchiveFiles = 50;
target.ArchiveDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-hh";
target.EnableArchiveFileCompression = true;
```

Alternative you can use dynamic-archive-mode and then use scheduled-task/cron-job to compress/move log-files to the wanted location:

```cs
target.FileName = @"C:\Logs\Log-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd-hh}.log";
target.ArchiveOldFileOnStartup = true;
target.MaxArchiveDays = 10;
target.MaxArchiveFiles = 50;
```

See also [Do not mix dynamic with static-archive-mode](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic)

Comment: In Dynamic FileName Archive-mode, it is mentioned that "it will roll / archive dynamically because of the layout-renderer-logic in ${date} (Changes on day-change)." Could you explain what it is? Does it mean that the log files will be moved to archive folder once every day automatically? And if yes, to which folder log files will be moved to?, as we are not supposed to specify "ArchiveFileName" in case of dynamic file name.

Comment: @tennisno1 Dynamic FileName Archive-mode doesn't support moving files (wiki also states that only static-archive-mode supports moving files along with file-compression). Dynamic-Archive-mode just rolls to the next file when the date-layout changes output (on day/hour change).

Comment: @tennisno1Alternative one can use dynamic-archive-mode, and then have a scheduled-task / cron-job that copies/compresses old log-files to the wanted location.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your NLog method to run some method after logging. Please refer to the following: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target.

MethodCall target: `Calls the specified static method on each log message and passes contextual parameters to it.`

You can create some code that uses `System.IO` to move and archive your code based on your needs.